# 'marked as' or 'marketed as'?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

I came across this sentence in a book, and even though I've looked at many dictionaries and it seems to me that this is a typo, I am still not quite sure.

> Zolpidem, the sleeping pill marked as Ambien, causes peculiar memory
> symptoms.

I googled "pill marked as" and "tablet marked as" and it appears that in those examples they're referring to a handwritten name and not a brand name on a printed label.

Is that a typo? If not, what exactly does it mean?

Comment: This would be a typo in American English. I can't speak for BrE or elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, a typo.  I don't think there is much point writing an answer. And you've correctly identified the intended word "marketed".  This is probably the result of a spelling mistake being corrected by a computer and the author not noticing the mistake.

Comment: @FeliniusRex - we have drugs with generic names _marketed_ with other names (sold under other names) in Britain as well. The drug mentioned is sold (or provided by the NHS) under the name Zolpidem tartrate (generic) or marketed as Stilnoct. It's one of the 'Z' drugs (Zaleplon, Zopiclone, Zolpidem) designed to avoid some of the problems caused by benzodiazepines.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey -- Ok, cool. Thanks for the info.